# include path using yocto bitbake

Tags: include, kernel, yocto, bitbake

I am new in Yocto. How can I find the include path when i build my yocto project with bitbake? 
I have a new kernel module but when I run bitbake I get the error "stdio.h: no such file or directory". I'm using a Udooneo board.

Answer (score 0):

Trying to add the include path manually is bad idea, as it will break instantly when trying to reproduce the build on another machine, or even when only a version changes.

The Yocto Project has rather extensive documentation on how to do this properly, even including an example module. All is to be found here: https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/2.5/kernel-dev/kernel-dev.html#working-with-out-of-tree-modules